# Create two level hash index

Tags: r, hash

Trying to create an hash index in R with two levels.

To avoid for loops and copy operations I came up with this code:

```
  library(hash)
  index.value.model <- hash(keys = 1:10, values = rep(list(list()),10 ))
  new.obj <- hash(keys = 1:100, values = rep(index.value.model, 100) )
```

> Error in rep(index.value.model, 100) :  attempt to replicate an object
>   of type 'S4'

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is due to the instrucion `rep(index.value.model, 100)` because `index.value.model` doesn't have a right format. It looks like this:

```
<hash> containing 10 key-value pair(s).
  1 : NULL
  10 : NULL
  2 : NULL
  3 : NULL
  4 : NULL
  5 : NULL
  6 : NULL
  7 : NULL
  8 : NULL
  9 : NULL
```

If you want a hash table with two levels, try this code:

```
hash(keys = 1:100, values = rep(c("1","2"), 50) )

<hash> containing 100 key-value pair(s).
  1 : 1
  10 : 2
  100 : 2
  11 : 1
  12 : 2
  13 : 1
  ...
  96 : 2
  97 : 1
  98 : 2
  99 : 1
```